# I am not able to logout from Stack Overflow. Could you please tell me how to log out?

Tags: discussion, logout

I am not able to logout from Stack Overflow. Could you please tell me how to log out?

Comment: Does this question belong here?

Comment: Its hard to find sir.

Answer (score 2):

#### Option is available on right side of header navigation menu -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the top bar right you will find an icon like a hamburger  [image: hamburger icon]

Click the icon and you will find the log out link [image: log out from site menu]

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the right menu and click logout